# Why doesn't Dbg seem to work within a for_each loop?

Tags: rust

Why doesn't `dbg!` work in this `for_each` loop? [Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fafdd99c792ad653f0ea534b92187188)

```rust
fn main() {
    let chars = "hello".chars();
    chars.clone().for_each(|x| dbg!(x));
}
```

I get this compile error:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:32
  |
4 |     chars.clone().for_each(|x| dbg!(x));
  |                                ^^^^^^^ expected (), found char
  |
  = note: expected type `()`
             found type `char`
  = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

I've tried passing in a reference to `x` too.

`println` works:

```rust
fn main() {
    let chars = "hello".chars();
    chars.clone().for_each(|x| println!("{:?}", x));
}
```

Comment: `for_each()` is not very idiomatic in my opinion, you should use a for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dbg!` returns the value you passed in, while `for_each` requires a unit type to be returned. `println!` returns a unit type.

We can make this work by adding `;`:

```rust
    chars.clone().for_each(|x| {dbg!(x);});
```

Comment: ... But it would be silly to write that when `for x in chars.clone() { dbg!(x); }` is shorter, idiomatic and perfectly clear.